Visionos method in hermes engines fails the pod install
I just updated the expo to version 51.0.28 and react native to version 0.74.5 using npx expo-doctor.
But now i have this error while starting the project, couldn't find any lead in the hermes engine github issues.
 Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Failed to load 'hermes-engine' podspec: 
[!] Invalid `hermes-engine.podspec` file: undefined method `visionos' for #<Pod::Specification name="hermes-engine/Pre-built">.

 #  from /Users/my-project/node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec:47
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #        ss.ios.vendored_frameworks = "destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework"
 >        ss.visionos.vendored_frameworks = "destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework"
 #        ss.osx.vendored_frameworks = "destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework"
 #  -------------------------------------------

Anyone run into this as well?
I tried, removing node_module, ios directory and installing it again, didn't help.
Then i upgraded the react native to `0.75.0` as it is the latest, didn't help.

Solution for now
On node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermers-engine/hermes-engine.podspec
i commented out
# ss.visionos.vendored_frameworks = "destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework"
and patched it with npx patch-package react-native
I will pay a close attention to issue to remove the patch as soon as possible.

Worked like a charm. Thank you.

I guess you will need to comment on every node_modules reset, It is Not a lasting solution.

if you patch it like i described, you don't have to do the extra work every time you delete node_modules

@mcnk never guessed that it will work, but it did.
thanks man

I was able to resolve this by upgrading my cocoapods to version 1.16.2 the latest at this time.
I had issues with sudo gem install cocoapods but was able to upgrade using brew install cocoapods.. I suspect that's how I originally installed it but had forgotten.

Update your system cocoapods.
Execute the following on your terminal to get the latest stable version:
sudo gem install cocoapods
Add --pre to get the latest pre release:
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre

I had issues with sudo gem install cocoapods but was able to upgrade using brew install cocoapods. I suspect that's how I originally installed it but had forgotten.

I had this exact problem with the same version of react-native and expo. I had to update my CocoaPods using homebrew (I'm on Mac) and that fixed the error. I am also running the latest version of xcode. Hope that helps you.

Could you tell us your version of cocoapods and xcode?
